# html - líneas impares en color gris

Tags: html, bash

Quiero hacer una tabla con html y que las líneas impares tengan fondo gris.
El código planteado al comienzo es el siguiente:

```
echo "<html>"
echo "<body>"
echo "<table border='1'>"
echo "<tbody tr:nth-child(2n+1){background: #D5DBF4;}"
```

Al ejecutar el script bash no tengo ningún error pero tampoco hace el cambio.
Qué está fallando?

Comment: Te falta meter el css en un tag `style=""`, no?

Comment: @Benito-B, esto ```echo "<tbody tr:nth-child(2n+1){background: #D5DBF4;}"``` como ```style``` dices? Lo he hecho siguiendo info de la web que dejo abajo y no tengo experiencia con HTML la verdad. http://www.forosdelweb.com/f53/poner-negrita-columna-tabla-html-991921/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ese código es incorrecto, estás intentando definir una regla de estilo en el HTML. Tienes dos opciones:

- Añadir el estilo a cada tr en una posición impar (usando un if en el bucle?), pero es más complejo que la segunda opción, que es
- Añadir el estilo como una regla de CSS:

```sh
echo "<html>"
echo "<head>"
echo "<style>"
echo "tbody tr:nth-child(odd) {"
echo "   background: #D5DBF4;"
echo "}"
echo "</style>"
echo "<head>"
echo "<body>"
...
```

```css
tr:nth-child(odd) {
  background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td> texto </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td> texto </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td> texto </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td> texto </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: +1 por el uso de `odd`. No lo conocía :)